# Wait for Handle to be set when using Process.Start

Tags: .net-4.0

I'm using `Process.Start` to start a console app from another app. After it's started I want to use P/Invoke to set the title of the window.

My problem is that immediately after starting the process the `MainWindowHandle` is 0. If I wait a bit the handle gets set.

I know I could use `WaitForIdleInput` if it wasn't a console app, but what do I do if it is?

My fall back is a sleep, or a loop that waits until MainWindowHandle is set, but is there a better way?